# Maintain code on bash scripts or Jenkins?

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins

I'm currently working with Linux VMs and I use Jenkins Pipelines to run various jobs written in bash. I have 2 options regarding where the code is wrote and maintained:

1. In pipelines with sh '#some code' (Git integrated)
2. In bash scripts placed in the VM with sh './bashscript'

Which one would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GIT to store scripts or code related, as GIT is a version control system, and all users who have access can access the file for viewing or making changes.
When the Jenkins job runs, a workspace folder is created on the server in which the job is running on, and the script would be copied from GIT into the folder.